# Not able to find hadoop configuration files

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop

I have just installed hadoop 2.8.1 on my ubuntu 14 environment.
After Installation I got these dirs and files under hadoop installation folder

Hadoop installation folder is /usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.8.1-src

```
BUILDING.txt       hadoop-build-tools     hadoop-dist               hadoop-maven-plugins  hadoop-project-dist  LICENSE.txt   pom.xml
dev-support        hadoop-client          hadoop-hdfs-project       hadoop-minicluster    hadoop-tools         NOTICE.txt    README.txt
hadoop-assemblies  hadoop-common-project  hadoop-mapreduce-project  hadoop-project        hadoop-yarn-project  patchprocess  start-build-env.sh
```

To complete installation we need to configure these files

```
/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh
/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml
/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/mapred-site.xml.template
/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xm

Note: If am correct these files would come out from hadoop installation . Right ?
```

But am no where able to find any of these files in hadoop installation folder and I have checked other possible locations as well, moreover conf folder is also missing.

I'm following Installation steps from here

http://www.bogotobogo.com/Hadoop/BigData_hadoop_Install_on_ubuntu_single_node_cluster.php

Can anyone tell what should I try further or What I'm doing wrong here ?

Can

Comment: You downloaded Hadoop sources, not Hadoop binaries.

Comment: @cricket_007, I have downloaded the first one from here http://mirrors.sonic.net/apache/hadoop/common/hadoop-2.8.1/ Is it wrong ? If yes then what difference is there in two ?

Comment: `-src` files require you to compile the code yourself. Unless you are an advanced user, and you want to modify the actual code in Hadoop, then that is not what you want. Also, I would follow the official documentation before going to anything third-party.  http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html

Comment: Besides, that site uses Hadoop 2.6, and gives you the necessary `wget` command. Hadoop 2.8.1 isn't the current "stable" version